# Oracle Client set oracle home

Tags: oracle, toad

In the Windows, I have issues in Oracle client driver, so Toad and Sql developer can't login. how to create an oracle home ? which bin path I should point to ? how to set up toad home and should point to which oracle bin ?

here is my oracle structure.

```
--oracle
    ---- client
        --- 11.2.0.1
    ---- product
        ---- 10.2.0
        ---- 11.1.0.6
```

Thanks

Comment: How many `oracle\bin` directories do you have??

Answer (score 0):

SQL developer is self contained and comes with it's own Oracle drivers.  An Oracle client is not necessary in order to make a connection.

- Open the program
- click on the green plus sign on the left side to create a new connection
- Enter a connection name which can be anything you want
- enter the username and password
- select a Basic connection type to use the built in drivers
- enter the machine name, port and database name in SID or service name depending on how your database was configured
- click test to confirm and you are good to go

Have you tried making a new Basic connection from SQL Developer as outlined above?  Visual Studio should not affect SQL developer and I'm doubtful that it would affect the database name or port.

Comment: for SQL developer, I connected to server successfully a few days ago. then I change something for Visual Studio, now doesn't work any more